# delete url from crawldb in nutch 1.3?

Tags: nutch, web-crawler, urlfetch

I crawl sites in nutch 1.3. now I want to delete a url from crawldb, how can I do this? how I read from crawldb? I want to see urls that exist in crawldb.

Answer (score 0):

To read from crawlDb you can use the CrawlDBReader class(org.apache.nutch.crawl package). To delete/remove a url from the crawlDb you can use try using the CrawlDBMerger class(org.apache.nutch.crawl package) with the "-filter" option. But I suggest writing a Mapreduce to delete urls according to your needs.